# Как получить color элемента? (React)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Как получить color элемента в React?

Не тот, что присвоен с помощью CSS, а тот, что используется, например, родительский или родительский родителя. То есть, мне нужно получить цвет `inherit`